# Differentiating constant piecewise function with interval dependent on x

Tags: functions, derivatives

Suppose there is a function

$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
1  & f(x) \geq C \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

for some unknown function $f(x)$ and constant $C$. What is $g'(x)$? Is it simply $0$ since g(x) is a constant piecewise function?

EDIT: As much as I don't like editing after an answer is given, let's assume for this case that $f(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: Such functions are exactly characteristic functions of a closed set. Clearly they are not differentiable at the boundary, while they are constant away from the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1  & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

And $C =1$. Now your $g(x)$ is exactly $f(x)$ which is the Dirichlet function, and is not differentiable at ANY (!) point.

Answer (score 1):

$$g'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac {g(x)-g (x_0)}{x-x_0} $$

with $g(x)-g (x_0)=0$ or $1$ or  $-1$.

the answer depends strongly on the expression of $f (x). $